# How to reconnect git branches to master after migration from svn?

Tags: git, svn, gitlab, svn2git

I have migrated a large svn repository to git using [svn2git](https://github.com/nirvdrum/svn2git). Now I have the following situation:

[image: git branch disconnected from master]

The image is from my GitLab overview. As you can see, the branches created with svn are not connected to the red master branch. Is it possible to "reconnect" the initial green commit to the master branch? Because of this, every branch is about 5k commits behind master and I'd like to fix that.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git-svn` is **not** the right tool for one-time conversions of repositories or repository parts. It is a great tool if you want to use Git as frontend for an existing SVN server, but for one-time conversions you should **not** use `git-svn`, but `svn2git` which is much more suited for this use-case.

The `svn2git` utility you have used is based on `git-svn` and thus suffers from most of the same drawbacks.

There are plenty tools called `svn2git`, the probably best one is the KDE one from https://github.com/svn-all-fast-export/svn2git. I strongly recommend using that `svn2git` tool. It is the best I know available out there and it is very flexible in what you can do with its rules files.

You will be easily able to configure `svn2git`s rule file to produce the result you want and it is a gazillion faster.

If you are not 100% about the history of your repository, `svneverever` from http://blog.hartwork.org/?p=763 is a great tool to investigate the history of an SVN repository when migrating it to Git.

---

Even though `git-svn` is easier to start with, here are some further reasons why using the KDE `svn2git` instead of `git-svn` is superior, besides its flexibility:

- the history is rebuilt much better and cleaner by `svn2git` (if the correct one is used), this is especially the case for more complex histories with branches and merges and so on
- the tags are real tags and not branches in Git
- with `git-svn` the tags contain an extra empty commit which also makes them not part of the branches, so a normal `fetch` will not get them until you give `--tags` to the command as by default only tags pointing to fetched branches are fetched also. With the proper svn2git tags are where they belong
- if you changed layout in SVN you can easily configure this with `svn2git`, with `git-svn` you will loose history eventually
- with `svn2git` you can also split one SVN repository into multiple Git repositories easily
- or combine multiple SVN repositories in the same SVN root into one Git repository easily
- the conversion is a gazillion times faster with the correct `svn2git` than with `git-svn`

You see, there are many reasons why `git-svn` is worse and the KDE `svn2git` is superior. :-)

Comment: You or course don't need the KDE SVN repo, but your own one you want to transform. There is a repo from the KDE guys with their rules files that they used to transform the various KDE projects. These can be used as examples for writing your own rules file to transform your SVN repository. But you don't actually need the KDE repository. Whatelse do you need besides https://github.com/svn-all-fast-export/svn2git and https://techbase.kde.org/Projects/MoveToGit/UsingSvn2Git and possibly http://blog.hartwork.org/?p=763 ?

Comment: I don't know, as I don't know your repo and its history. If you want to change the history, you can freely do it after the migration if a different ruleset does not produce the result you expect. You can make the parent of that commit a different commit, you can make it a parent-less root commit, you can do whatever you want, especially as long as you didn't publish the history and thus are free to modify it however you like.